# MySQLdb OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (24)")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I been at this for about 2 days and cant figure out the reason for the failure. So hopefully someone here can help.

I have some multithreading code where a method makes a query like this:

```
make_query(self, test_name):
    ModelObject.objects.filter(test=test_name)
```

and every thread's target is the method above like so:

```
Thread(target=make_query, args=(test_name,))
```

and create many threads. However, i get an exception like:

```
Exception in thread Thread-275:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/myapp/sources/model.py", line 23, in make_query
    for row in self.queryset:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 837, in execute_sql
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 389, in as_sql
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 366, in compile
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 79, in as_sql
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 366, in compile
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 157, in as_sql
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 150, in process_lhs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 625, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 184, in data_types
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 359, in mysql_version
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 264, in get_new_connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (24)")
```

I have tried increasing the number of connections in mysql (set max_connections variable) but this does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many open files. You need to increase the open_files_limit in your MySQL configuration file. By default, the variable is set to 1,024 open files. Though I would maybe reconsider the design of you application too, 1,024 is quite much.

Comment: not true, 
Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 65536 |

Im nowhere near my limit.

Comment: @Rafael: Are you sure? I have had this problem myself and searched nearly two weeks why my system would crash after 2 hours each time. It turned out that a process totally unreated to MySQL was not closing files and whenever that process had 1019 files in use MySQL would no longer connect... (my embarrassing error was closing a MSSQL connection with `conn.close` instead of `conn.close()`, so look out for that, too)